# Codename One:Container moves down when loading toastbar

Tags: codenameone, mobile-application

I am developing app using codename one .On login screen when toastbar gets loading container moves down.
I have attached screen shot [image: toastbar.jpg]in which i have shown exact error.
 If I rotate the device or simulator it produced same effect.I used border layout and value of includeNativeBool = true
Can you please let me know how to resolve it? 
Thanks in advance[image: Form Structure]

I have attched screen shots of my form structure

Comment: Without code I'm just guessing. I guess you used things like `setY()` and other problematic methods to position things. The toastbar lays out the form so this might happen if you do something problematic.

Comment: I have designed forms through codename one designer . For ToastBar I have used below code "ToastBar.Status status = ToastBar.getInstance().createStatus();
  status.setMessage(msg);
  status.setExpires(sec);
  status.setShowProgressIndicator(flag);     
  status.show();

Answer (score 0):

There is no scrollability in this layout. I'm also guessing you assigned percentage heights in the table layout and some nuances might change.

`Container1` should be scrollable on the y axis but that might break your entire layout because you rely on problematic behaviors of table layout so it will fit "exactly" it wasn't designed for that.